# Building up a variable with numbers in brackets for a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I am beginning work on creating my first for loop (for 29 times - 0 to 28) but the numbers have to be presented in square brackets.
I eventually want to build of a string of 0's and 1's (zeros and ones). The value of cellData will always be 0 (zero) or 1 (one).
I want to change the cellindex variable first number starting at zero and finishing at 28. e.g.
And later do the same thing with the second number (in another loop).

```
[0,0]; [1,0]; [2,0]; [3,0];....... [28,0]; (First column).
[0,1]; [1,1]; [2,1]; [3,1];....... [28,1]; (Second column).
```

Where the first numbers represent the rows and the second numbers represents the columns in  at table.
The idea being the row variable can be incremented each time in the the loop  by 1.

First I need to find a way of setting up variables and then combining them together to get the variable: cellindex.
Unless there is a better way to do this?
Whatever I try, I keep getting not defined errors or cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined, Unexpected token etc...
I have included some of my poor attempts at building this below (commented in the code).

```
//var row = 0;
//var column = 0;
//var cellIndex = [row,column];
//var cellIndex = [row + "," + column];
//var cellindex = "[ + row + "," + column + ]";
//var cellindex = "[ + row + ',' + column + ]";
//var cellIndex = [+row+","+column+];
//var cellIndex = [ +row+ +','+ +column+ ]; 
var cellIndex = [0,0];
var cellData = sheet.getCellState(cellIndex);
var celldata = "";
celldata += (cellData);

console.log('Cell Data: ' + celldata);
```

Well the below works but it is huge code and has to be repeated for all 7 columns.

I cannot figure it out and if no-one else knows how to how to build up the the cellindex value with code then I cannot even attempt a loop to shorten it.

```
var cellIndex = [0,0];
var cellData = sheet.getCellState(cellIndex);
var celldata = "";
celldata += (cellData);

cellIndex = [1,0];
cellData = + sheet.getCellState(cellIndex);
var celldata = celldata;
celldata += (cellData);

cellIndex = [2,0];
cellData = + sheet.getCellState(cellIndex);
var celldata = celldata;
celldata += (cellData);

cellIndex = [3,0];
cellData = + sheet.getCellState(cellIndex);
var celldata = celldata;
celldata += (cellData);


//Repeat another 25 times

console.log('Cell Data: ' + celldata);
```

This is answered now, thanks to lucas.
I can output the data for each column in the format I require. Which is, for example:

```
1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1
```

Comment: Where did sheet come from?

Comment: That is in the jQuery external file. The not commented code works. but I really don't want to do this 29 times and get the single variable each time and have to combine them at the end. Would be over 130  lines of code. So I was hoping I could create a for loop to do it?

Comment: @flakie, can you include a sample of how you want the output to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your cell index goes from [0,0] to [27,6] maybe this will help

```
var data ={};
for (var i=0;i<28;i++) {
    for (var j=0;j<7;j++) {
    var cellIndex = [i,j];
    if(!data["col"+j]){
    data["col"+j]=[]
    }
    var cellIndex = [i,j];
    var cellData = sheet.getCellState(cellIndex);
    data["col"+j].push(cellData)
    }   
}
console.log(data)
console.log(data.col1) // data.col1 will give you an array of column 1 values for further processing
console.log(data.col1.toString()) // this will give you a string you can copy from the console to paste elsewhere
```

If you wanted to split the data out into rows or columns you would just output an array (or something) at the end of each loop iteration

Comment: Thanks for this. Looks really good. It is outputting to the console log with no errors on a testing table that is [0,0] to [11,23] so I set  i<12 and j<24,  while I test. But it is in a format I am unsure what to do with. How would I output just one column to the console in the format for example: 101110010111 (if this was the data in column 0)?

Comment: on the test table I have set i<12 and j<1 which is giving me just the first column. but it is over several lines in console log, with a count(?) indicator when each number is identical.

Comment: have a look at my edited answer, maybe that will be more useful

Comment: Thank you. Looks great. So I can get each column out of the array (when I figure that out), Miles better and shorter than the code I was going to implement, for sure. Thanks a million. Sorry I just noticed the line in your code to get column 1. Missed that in my copy/paste initially.

Comment: Just a quick one. What is a __proto__: Object?

Comment: I edited my answer to add a bit more detail about how you can use this. Prototype is an in-built way that JavaScript objects can be extended. Not really useful for you here.

Comment: Thanks again lucas. Brilliant answer and thanks for the prototype explanation. I hope that this question and answer is useful to others in the future. It is invaluable to me.

Answer (score 0):

What about this

```
for (let i=0;i<28;++i) {
    for (let j=0;j<28;++j) {
        sheet.setCellState([i,j],[i,j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ted but I get "Cannot read property 'get' of undefined" in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout arrays in javascript since is the type of data you are presenting.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array

Comment: Thanks, Read it but don't see how to achieve what I need to do. Need to get this done so will just write out the code 29 times and collate all the variable values at the end.